# Can someone provide a table of content for Detroit: Become Human?

Tags: detroit-become-human

I've just started Quantic Dream's "Detroit: Become Human" and am looking for a list of all chapters, with a few spoil-free notes:

- chapter's name
- if the chapter is missable
- if it's mutually exclusive with another chapter
- any other relevant info suitable for a "table of content" of some sort

I just want to get a quick overview of the game and be able to compare my progress with a friend's. I'm especially interested in the details described above. The number of available walkthroughs is already skyrocketing but the ones I've found provide names only and are incomplete.

Has anyone finished the game and could list me a complete list of the chapters' names and "status", please?

Answer (score 4):

In case you're just interested in how many chapters there are and the titles, here's the complete list:

- The Hostage
- Opening
- Shades of Color
- A New Home
- The Painter
- Partners
- Stormy Night
- Broken
- The Interrogation
- Fugitives
- From the Dead
- Waiting for Hank…
- On the Run
- Jericho
- The Nest
- Time to Decide
- Zlatko
- Russian Roulette
- Spare Parts
- The Eden Club
- The Pirates’ Cove
- The Bridge
- The Stratford Tower
- Public Enemy
- Midnight Train
- Capitol Park
- Meet Kamski
- Freedom March
- Last Chance, Connor
- Crossroads
- Night of the Soul
- Battle for Detroit

For a total of 32 chapters.

Comment: Just to extend, no chapters are missable (except because of character deaths)  but some chapters have completely different flowcharts based on what a given character's story has been. Especially in the last few big chapters, characters could be in a completely different state and their chapter content never overlaps with anything from the same chapter in one of their different states - **but the chapter name remains the same**.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for ?

**Chapter 01 - The Hostage**
The prologue chapter of Detroit: Become Human serves as training for the game's main mechanics and controls as well as an introduction to the android protagonist Connor.

**Chapter 02 - Opening**
The chapter called Opening works as another opening to the game, this time serving as an introduction for Kara.

**Chapter 03 - Shades of Color**
The third chapter jumps into the shoes of Markus and gives players their first detailed look into the political climate surrounding the relationship between humans and androids.

**Chapter 04 - A New Home**
The chapter called A New Home introduces follows Kara as she goes about her standard android cleaning duties. This chapter also introduces Alice and gives players a few crucial choices that will affect later paths.

**Chapter 05 - The Painter**
The Painter follows along as Markus and his owner Carl pontificate about the future.

**Chapter 06 - Partners**
The chapter known as Partners sees Connor and Lt. Anderson help solve a crime, giving players a chance to make their first decisions that will have a major affect on the game's overall narrative.

**Chapter 07 - Stormy Night**
Stormy Night is where players will come to understand the gravity of their decisions, following along as Kara and Alice deal with the problematic whims of Todd.

**Chapter 08 - Broken**
Broken is a fairly quick chapter with only two separate endings, each of which having a distinct affect on Markus' storyline.

**Chapter 09 - The Interrogation**
The Interrogation is a follow-up to the chapter Partners, where Connor uses his detective skills to learn some new information.

**Chapter 10 - Fugitives**
Fugitives follows along with Kara and Alice as they search for a temporary place to rest.

**Chapter 11 - From the Dead**
From the Dead sees Markus making a couple of decisions before finding a way out of his situation.

**Chapter 12 - Waiting For Hank**
Waiting For Hank follows along with Connor as he and Hank tool around the police station looking for new leads.

**Chapter 13 - On The Run**
Coming soon.

**Chapter 14 - Jericho**
The chapter Jericho follows along as Markus looks at graffiti and searches for the area known as Jericho.

**Chapter 15 - The Nest**
Coming soon.

**Chapter 16 - Time To Decide**
Following up on the events of Jericho, Time To Decide sees Markus and his new android companions discuss some possible plans of action.

**Chapter 17 - Zlatko**
Coming soon.

**Chapter 18 - Russian Roulette**
Coming soon.

**Chapter 19 - Spare Parts**
Coming soon.

**Chapter 20 - The Eden Club**
Coming soon.

Source: http://www.shacknews.com/article/105092/choices-endings-and-walkthrough---detroit-become-human

Comment: The format is perfect but as you can see, the list is partial, most descriptions are missing and the reference article ends up with a note specifying that "more chapter breakdowns (...) will be posted in due time". If you can find a complete list though, this is what I'm looking for.